# It's too unclear which vote arrows are selected here on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: A picture of the post vote buttons from here on Meta]

These post buttons are too unclear I think, and I've gotten confused into thinking that I had upvoted a post I disliked and vice versa. It's tricky to show what the highlighted state is when the colour scheme is limited to grey-scale. I think it could be improved by removing the black from the unselected button: make black and white be the active state, and two shades of grey be inactive.

Here are some buttons from some other Meta sites to compare:

[image: Vote buttons from Meta.Christianity.SE] [image: Vote buttons from Meta.English.SE] [image: Vote buttons from a beta site's Meta]

Comment: -1 because it's pretty clear to me, especially with a minimum of experimentation. :-)

Comment: +1 White does look like confirmation

Comment: @ChrisW: It is pretty clear to me too, but I gave the complaint an upvote. If it is confusing for some users, then it should be changed: a non-selfish thought.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed some time ago (and beyond that, now all vote buttons look the same across child metas). When you vote now, the arrow changes to black from grey (the same color used for the unselected favorite star and flag/upvote buttons on comments):

> [image]